# What do the abbreviations mean in Dragon Ball Z?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

I have watch all of Dragon Ball, Dragon Ball Z, and that which is available of Dragon Ball Super, but still can't figure this out. What do the abbreviations for the different Super Saiyan transformations stand for in DBZ? For example, I've seen "SSGSS." Does this mean "Super Saiyan God Super Saiyan?" What are the abbreviations for Super Saiyan 1 and Super Saiyan 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. SSGSS stands for Super Saiyan God Super Saiyan. I know it doesn't make any sense, but according to the info I gathered, "**Super Saiyan God Super Saiyan**, more commonly known as **Super Saiyan Blue**, is a form that can be accessed after absorbing the power of Super Saiyan God and then combining it with the Super Saiyan form."

For other forms like Super Saiyan 1 and Super Saiyan 2, no fancy abbreviations are used. They are generally known as SSJ/SS for Super Saiyan 1, SSJ2/SS2 for Super Saiyan 2, and so on.
There are also other forms like USSJ (Ultra Super Saiyajin), which are sometimes confused with Super Saiyan 2 or 3, but note that they are different. You can find more details on [this](http://dbzwarriors.com/saiyanforms.shtml) site also.

Comment: But what does the 'J' mean in SSJ and SSJ2?

Comment: @ThePickleTickler I believe the J comes from the fact that in Japanese, the Saiyans are actually called the _Saiya-jin_. _Jin_ in Japanese means "people" and is the usual suffix for a nationality (e.g. _Amerika-jin_ is "American", _Furansu-jin_ is "French"). When the show was brought out in English it was changed to _Saiyan_, using the English suffix _-an_ that we seen in _Italian_ and _Martian_. I actually think that would make a good question all on its own, though.

Comment: @Torisuda Asked in a new question

Answer (score 1):

SSJ1  =  Super Saiya Jin 1

SSJ2  =  Super Saiya Jin 2

SSJ3  =  Super Saiya Jin 3

SSG   =  Super Saiya God

SSGSS = Super Saiyan God Super Saiyan

SSJB/SSB = Super Saiya Jin Blue<sup>*</sup>

LSSJ = Legendary Super Saiya Jin

SSJR = Super Saiyan Jin Rage

<sup>*It's the last transformation with a new name. The new name was introduced in the manga because the fans were complaining the former name was too complicated.</sup>

Comment: Should be noted that SSB and SSGSS are the same.

Comment: This is the correct answer however `SSJ` is what super saiyajin 1 is. There is no `1` after it. It's been pretty rigorously discussed here for referrence http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/960298-dragon-ball-raging-blast/52296870